# Pass structure (or class) from C++ dll to C# (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, plugins, interop

I am writing a wrapper to get some data from a sensor. While I have no problems with passing int, float and arrays of them, I have difficulties to grasp how to pass a structure.

Code summary

**C++ side**

The structure is as follows:

```
struct HandInfo
{
    int id;
    float x, y, z;
};
```

At some point one static, globally visible HandInfo leftHand is filled with values which are retrievable through the following wrapper function:

```
extern EXPORT_API HandInfo MyWrapper_getLeftHand()
{
    return handtracker.getLeftHand();
}
```

where *handtracker* is just an instance of the wrapped class.

**C# side**

Once declared the extern function

```
[DllImport("MyWrapper")]
private static extern HandInfo MyWrapper_getLeftHand();
```

On the C# side, ideally, I would have the same struct type

```
public struct HandInfo
{
    public int id;
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

and assign a variable

```
HandInfo hi = MyWrapper_getLeftHand(); // NAIVELY WRONG CODE
```

which, understandably, doesn't work.

What's the way to achieve this?

I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you all for your time.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Good point David, I am using the dll in Unity 3D which, if I use the code above, just crashes very silently and I don't know how to intercept the call stack in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work correctly (at least, here in a small C++ + C# project I have, I was able to make it work with that `struct`, both in x86 and x64)

```
[DllImport("MyWrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern HandInfo MyWrapper_getLeftHand();
```

The only thing, you must declare the `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl`.

Comment: What is the purpose of that convention?
Thanks, I'll try asap.

Comment: @SteakOverflow It describes how the parameters/return values are put in memory when the call is made. C/C++ normally uses Cdecl, Windows API StdCall

Comment: Man that worked!!! Thanks.
Do you know if that would work even if I have arrays in my struct?

Comment: @SteakOverflow It becomes ugly... There are [fixed size buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zycewsya.aspx) in C#, but they require unsafe code, and they are a little pain to use (because they aren't really C# arrays, so you can't use C# array methods)

Comment: I had a look to fixed size buffers but is that really the simplest way? No chance to avoid unsafe mode?

Comment: @SteakOverflow No. In general it is easier if you do memory allocation C#-side and use the memory/structs received from C# in the C/C++ side. The structs are passed as `ref`/`out`, the memory as `byte[]`