# Integration between C++ DLL and C# Unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dllimport

I'm having issues with C++ Dll Integration with Unity. I found some code in the web (link at the end of article) but it doesn't work.

This is my C++ DLL code (I want to send unity a structure with some points):

```
struct Pontos {
int i;
float f;
};
Pontos **pontos;
DllExport bool SetPoints(Pontos *** a, int *i)
{

    pontos = new Pontos*[4];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            pontos[j] = new Pontos; // Actually create each object.
            pontos[j]->i = j;
            pontos[j]->f = (float)j;
        }
        *a = pontos;
        *i = 4;
        return true;
    }
```

From the unity code, I get the following error:

> No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name

I don't know what this means.
Here I try to get those points and save them in c#:

```
[DllImport("dll")]
private static extern bool SetPoints(out IntPtr ptrResultVerts, out int resultVertLength);
public struct Pontos
{
    int i;
    float f;
};     
void Start()
{ 
    IntPtr ptrNativeData = IntPtr.Zero;
    int itemsLength = 0;

    bool success = SetPoints(out ptrNativeData, out itemsLength);
    if (!success)
    {
        return;
    }

    Pontos[] SArray = new Pontos[itemsLength];  // Where the final data will be stored.
    IntPtr[] SPointers = new IntPtr[itemsLength];

    Debug.Log("Length: " + itemsLength); // Works!
    Marshal.Copy(ptrNativeData, SPointers, 0, itemsLength); // Seems not to work.

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Pointer: " + SPointers[i]);
        SArray[i] = (Pontos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(SPointers[i], typeof(Pontos));
    }
```

I got this code from [Can't marshal array of stucts from C++ to C# in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390856/cant-marshal-array-of-stucts-from-c-to-c-sharp-in-unity).

Comment: You forgot to plaace `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential),Serializable]` to the top of `public struct Pontos`....

Comment: In the c++ only or need do something else em c# too?

Comment: Reading some articles I saw that serialization is not necessary with Marshalling

Comment: The "No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name" occures when the very first type in a (behaviour) file is does not have the same name, try moving the other types, such as `Pontos` to a different file. Should work a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the dll specifying the calling convention

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

I don't think the error

> No MonoBehaviour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the
>   file name

has anything to do with your code. Check your class name and your script name. Do they correspond?

Finally, I'm not sure about the `out` modifier in the method signature as I never have to deal with triple pointers on the C++ side. If your goal is to fill an array of `Pontos` structures than you shouldn't need it.

See also [Pass structure (or class) from C++ dll to C# (Unity 3D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123636/pass-structure-or-class-from-c-dll-to-c-sharp-unity-3d)